# how to configure an authorized service object using Google OAuth 2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

On the following link there is code which should access the Google Calendar api using OAuth 2.0. Unfortunately it uses the Draft 10 Client Library which is apparently deprecated.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/instantiate

The latest Client Library is google-api-java-client-1.12.0-beta. From what I can make out things have changed a lot since the Draft 10 Client Library and I can't work out how to rewrite this code for the current Client Library.

The deprecated code is shown below.

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.draft10.AccessTokenResponse;
import   com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.draft10.GoogleAccessProtectedResource;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.draft10.GoogleAccessTokenRequest.GoogleAuthorizationCodeGrant;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.draft10.GoogleAuthorizationRequestUrl;

import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;

import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

...

public void setUp() throws IOException {
    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

    // The clientId and clientSecret are copied from the API Access tab on
    // the Google APIs Console
    String clientId = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
    String clientSecret = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET";

    // Or your redirect URL for web based applications.
    String redirectUrl = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
    String scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar";

    // Step 1: Authorize -->
    String authorizationUrl = new GoogleAuthorizationRequestUrl(clientId, redirectUrl,   scope)
    .build();

    // Point or redirect your user to the authorizationUrl.
    System.out.println("Go to the following link in your browser:");
    System.out.println(authorizationUrl);

    // Read the authorization code from the standard input stream.
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("What is the authorization code?");
    String code = in.readLine();
    // End of Step 1 <--

   // Step 2: Exchange -->
    AccessTokenResponse response = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeGrant(httpTransport,     jsonFactory,
    clientId, clientSecret, code, redirectUrl).execute();
   // End of Step 2 <--

  GoogleAccessProtectedResource accessProtectedResource = new GoogleAccessProtectedResource(
    response.accessToken, httpTransport, jsonFactory, clientId, clientSecret,
    response.refreshToken);

  Calendar service = new Calendar(httpTransport, accessProtectedResource, jsonFactory);
  service.setApplicationName("YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME");
   ...
}
...
```

Can anyone tell how to rewrite this code so it works with the current Client Library?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the documentation of the Google Drive API, which is up to date:

https://developers.google.com/drive/credentials

Then it shouldn't be hard to replace the Drive scope with the Calendar scope and to instantiate the correct Calendar class for the service instead of a Drive service object.

If that situation happens again, the best to be sure you can find the latest version of code samples is to have a look directly on the website of the Google APIs Client Library for Java. You can have a look at it's [wiki about auth](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2) but also have a look at [the sample apps](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse?repo=samples) which they make sure are compiling and working with he latest version of the library (it's just harder to keep all the docs up to date sometimes)

Comment: Thank you Nivco for your reply, you have given me a lot of information to learn and think about.